# Display a json response with special characters

Tags: javascript, json, special-characters

I am getting an ajax response with the following `message` :

```
"L'insertion a &eacute;t&eacute; effectu&eacute;e."
```

in frensh and when i try to display it :

```
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = message;
```

which puts the message in its initial form , how can i get it to be displayed like this :

```
"L'insertion a été effectuée."
```

Comment: Is that message correct? It looks like "de la piece" has been completely taken out?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense.  Using `innerHTML` *would* result in those HTML entities being properly decoded into characters.  Are you sure that's the code you're using?

Comment: @Andy E  that's exactly what i find strange here , the only thing i omitted is how im parsing my json response .

Comment: @Mona: then maybe it's possible your JSON response isn't encoded properly.  Check for things like `&amp;eacute;` instead of `&eacute;`.

Comment: @Endy E thanks a lot , there was &amp;eacute; in my response

Answer (score 1):

This should be able to help you: http://www.naveen.com.au/javascript/jquery/encode-or-decode-html-entities-with-jquery/289